# Installing EMBOSS using Cygwin64 Terminal on windows

Tags: python-2.7, biopython, emboss

I'm fairly new to BioPython and wanted to use the EMBOSS needle and water tool on Windows 7 64 bit platform using Anaconda Spyder python 2.7 IDE, after adding the BioPython library in the Libs folder. To do this, I'm trying to install EMBOSS first using Cygwin 64 terminal following the [instructions](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/download/cygwin.html).

I downloaded the [EMBOSS package](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/EMBOSS-6.5.7.tar.gz.99290173-0.html). After uncompressing the folder and going to the directory of the uncompressed folder and performing the following command:

```
./configure --without-x CFLAGS=-s
```

I receive the following error message:

```
$ ./configure --without-x CFLAGS=-s
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for icc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
configure:
    error: in `/home/Khajag/EMBOSS-6.5.7/EMBOSS-6.5.7':
configure:
    error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH See `config.log'
    for more details
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: which linux OS are you using?

Comment: What is the output of "$ echo $PATH" or "$ which gcc" or "$ which icc"?

Comment: It's not Linux... I'm trying to install it over windows using Cygwing 64 terminal

Comment: as per your questions about the paths: $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Autodesk Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk/Backburner:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/Scripts

Comment: $ which gcc
which: no gcc in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Autodesk Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk/Backburner:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/Scripts)

Comment: $ which icc
which: no icc in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Autodesk Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk/Backburner:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/Scripts)

Comment: Well, the error is telling you that you need a C compiler. But you don't seem to have one installed (either gcc, cc or icc). You have to install it in Cygwin before attempting to install EMBOSS. I don't know nothing about Cygwin, so a Google search might lead you to the answer. Try installing something called "Devel" package for Cygwin... and be ready for other dependencies missed!

Comment: Try this: http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/cygwin/part2/